# What is the minimal length of a "Diagonal" in a Torus?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, fundamental-groups, geodesic

Given a Riemannian torus $(T,d)$ with fundamental group $\pi_1(T)=\langle a,b \mid ab=ba \rangle$. Denote for any $\gamma \in \pi_1(T)$ the infimum length of all representatives of $\gamma$ by $L(\gamma)$.

Is there a way to get a upper bound on $L(ab)$ in terms of $L(a),L(b)$ and the volume of $T$?

An obvious one is $L(ab) \leq L(a) + L(b)$, but i guess, there are better results.

This is inspired by [Loewner's torus inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner%27s_torus_inequality).

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for an upper bound for a particular unit-area metric, or over the class of all unit-area metrics conformal to a particular unit-area metric, or something else (such as the above, but for flat metrics)?

Comment: I am asking for a general upper bound for arbitrary Riemannian metrics on the Torus, but I would be interested in any of the other approaches as well.

Comment: I think an equivalent formulation is the following: Given a geodesic rectangle with any Riemannian metric such that the sides are of length $a$ and $b$. Is there an upper bound for the (shorter) diagonal in terms of a, b and the volume of the rectangle?